# Fusion Table Google Mapping - How to add an additional drop down selection that will update the visualization

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am using the code provided here to make a climate change temperature map.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples/source/browse/trunk/fusiontables/dynamic_styling_template.html

The existing code allows to visually query different columns of "total urban and rural housing units", and "total urban housing units". I have modified the code to make it so the queried columns are percentile columns (10th Percentile/20th Percentile/30th Percentile/40th Percentile/50th Percentile/60th Percentile/70th Percentile/80th Percentile/90th Percentile). In my Fusion Table there is also a separate column for Month, which relates to the percentile values.

sloppy example:

```
Month    10th Percentile    20th Percentile
1              1                            4545
2              34                           565
3              45645                      565
 ..
12            5656                        565
```

Now, I can't figure out how to add code to create an additional drop down menu query based on month. I've tried playing around with Fusion Tables API https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/ , but can't figure out how to get the code I need. I want it so that, when a specific month and percentile is selected via two separate drop down menus, that together, the fusion table map will update the polygon visualization colour values.

So, I am hoping someone can provide me the javascript code to add in another drop down menu for only the month column, and that it updates the visualization based on only the selected month's values.

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://kh-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/code/instructions.html), you can't change the schema once you have data on the table:

> ...once you have started collecting data, you can not make any changes to
>   the form or Fusion Table.